# In OCaml how do you distinguish * from ,?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I'm trying to implement a tree with key - value tuples. I've tried the following along with many variations of replacing `*` with `,` and vice versa.

```
type ('k,'v) tree =
  | Leaf
  | Node of ('k*'v) * ('k*'v) tree * ('k*'v) tree;;

module type Dictionary = sig 
  type ('k,'v) t
  val empty : ('k,'v) t
end;;
module TreeDict : Dictionary = struct 
  type ('k,'v) t = ('k*'v) tree
  let empty = Leaf
end;;
```

With this it says the tree constructor takes two arguments, but if I change `*` to `,` in the constructor I get a non-descript error. I'm not very clear on when to use which and I'm guessing that's the source of the error. I know you make specific instances of tuples with the comma, and type definitions that are constructed with tuples with the star. But here it's not always clear which is which, or if actually some other rule is at play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `*` symbol is used to separate elements of a tuple in data type definitions. The `,` symbol is used to separate type variables in a parametric type which has more than one variable.

E.g., in `Student of name * age * class` we define a constructor with three arguments. To create a value using this constructor we pass arguments as a tuple `Student ("Jon",21,"CS")`. Note, that we have used comma to separate arguments of a tuple.

In your example, type `('k,'v) tree` is parametric with two type variables. Therefore, we need to refer to it always, like this (Not `('k * 'v) tree`, but `('k,'v) tree`).

The correct definition should look like this

```
type ('k,'v) tree =
  | Leaf
  | Node of 'k * 'v * ('k,'v) tree * ('k,'v) tree
```

Note that the parenthesis around `('k * 'v)` has a special semantics, as the following defines a constructor with four arguments (key,value,lhs,rhs),

```
  | Node of 'k * 'v * ('k,'v) tree * ('k,'v) tree
```

while the following

```
  | Node of ('k * 'v) * ('k,'v) tree * ('k,'v) tree
```

Defines a constructor with three arguments,e.g., `Node (data,lhs,rhs)`, where `data` is represented as a `(key,value)` pair. The representation with 3 arguments will be using more memory, because each `(key,value)` pair will be stored in a boxed representation, externally to the tree. Or graphically<sup>1</sup>,

```
  4 arguments              3 arguments
  representation           representation 
  (5 words/node)           (7 words/node)

  +--------+               +--------+
  | header |               | header |
  +--------+               +--------+     +--------+
  |  key   |               | data   |---->| header | 
  +--------+               +--------+     +--------+
  |  value |      vs.      | left   |     |   key  |
  +--------+               +--------+     +--------+
  |  left  |               | right  |     | value  |
  +--------+               +--------+     +--------+
  |  right |
  +--------+
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> in the real implementation, the `data` pointer will actually point to `key`, i.e., to the first field of a boxed value, but I think that conceptually it is better to ignore this implementation detail.

Comment: In that last part, _"Defines a constructor with two arguments: (binding, lhs, rhs)..."_ do you mean _three_ arguments? I've been confused by this before too and I don't know where to begin reading about it... Maybe you can show how each constructor variant would also be used to construct a value of its type?

Comment: @user633183, yep, I've meant three, of course, just a typo. I added a graphical example, hope it clarifies things.